# Yii2 rest controller's AccessControl filter redirects to login page

Tags: rest, access-control, yii2

ApiController:

```php
<?php
namespace frontend\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\rest\Controller;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;

/**
 * API
 */

class ApiController extends Controller
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actionTest()
    {
        echo 'here';
    }
}
```

When I open /api/test in browser AccessControl redirects to the login page. How to show json formatted error with 403 status code?

Thanks!

Comment: please specify in behaviors that this action is allowed to with and without login

Comment: AccessControl class works totally on based of user session, it can not be used in Rest controller until and unless overridden for rest based functionality

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should add denyCallback to change this behavior:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
            'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                throw new \yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException('You are not allowed to access this page');
            }
        ],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question asks how to return the data as JSON and not (assuming) HTML. Your probably getting the data returned as the HTML source of the login page.

You need to edit your config and tell Yii to return all responses as JSON. This should be done for (most) API systems using Yii. Half the guides out there skip this.

```
'components' => [
    'user' => [
        // ...
        'request' => [
            'class' => '\yii\web\Request',
            'enableCookieValidation' => false,
            'parsers' => [
                'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
            ],
        ],
        'response' => [
            'format' => yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
            'charset' => 'UTF-8',
        ],
    ],
],
```

The `response` config is what tells Yii to return all data as JSON instead of rendering the webpage HTML source. I added the `request` config just for clarity. It tells Yii to handle the requests as JSON (ie: when posting data). Both combined will give you a two-way JSON API.

Looking at your AccessControl rules, your rules state to deny everyone who isn't logged in for that controller. If your other controllers extend from this ApiController, then ALL of their actions will probably be denied too. I'm not sure the role of AccessControl when behind REST, but that is how it would work in the normal web app. So you would probably want to ensure the route to "login" and "signup" are accessible to guests, or nobody would be able to login or register lol. - Does AccessControl even work for REST?